# Не работает часть кода с кнопками TeleBot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import telebot
from telebot.apihelper import send_message
import configur
from telebot import types

client = telebot.TeleBot(configur.config['token'])


@client.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def get_user_info(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='ДА', callback_data='yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='НЕТ' , callback_data='no')

    markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Would you like to know a little information about you',
        reply_markup=markup_inline
    )

@client.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item_id = types.KeyboardButton('MY ID')
        item_username = types.KeyboardButton('MY NICKNAME')
        markup_reply.add(item_id, item_username)
        client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Click on one of the buttons',
            reply_markup=markup_reply
        )

    elif call.data == 'no':
        pass


@client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text(message):
    if message.text == 'MY ID':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Your ID: {message.from_user.id}')

    elif message.text == 'MY NICKNAME':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Your Nickname: {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}')


def bot_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'hello':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello, unknown user)')

    elif message.text.lower() == 'what to see?' or message.text.lower() == 'what to see':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Илюзия обмана')

client.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Напишите что и где не так. Опишите проблему.

Comment: Весь код до функции bot_text не работает, хотя ошибок нету

Answer (score 1):

У Вас отсутсвует декоратор для функции bot_text():

```py
@client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_text(message):
    ...
```